# How to force load custom User Control's javascript to load when control is displayed dynamically in ASP?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

I have a user control, which contains a bunch of javascript code.
At the beginning of my javascript code, I've put a simple console.log('test') to see whether my javascript code has been loaded.

If I add my user control to a page, it displays its content correctly, and the test log message also appears in the browser's developer console.

However, if I put my user control in an ASP:Panel, that has Visible=false set by default, and I set its Visible property later, then the panel and the user control in it shows up correctly, but the related javascript code does not load in. Neither the methods in it are not callable when I try to call via ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript, nor the "test" log message is displayed in the console.

Any suggestions on what could I try to force my Javascript to load when the User Control is loaded and displayed later?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've found the issue.
My control was in an Update Panel that prevented my javascript to load in.
After I added a PostBackTrigger to my update panel to the other control that also made my asp:Panel visible, then it forced a full page load, and my user control's javascript code also loaded correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).